# Draw line in multiline TextField of MUI (ReactJS, MUI, TextField)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I am trying to add a solid line in TextField multiline of mui, but i don't know how to do it.
The result I want:
[The result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXOgP.png)
This is what I have
[textfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2JF2.png).
My code looks like this:

```
<TextField
                                    multiline
                                    rows={2}
                                    name='address'
                                    variant='standard'
                                    label="Địa chỉ"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with custom styling of the textarea, the first thing i'm thinking of is two lines which are going to be absolute positioned and the container of the textarea is going to be relative for this lines, the distance between the top and the bottom line is going to be the line height of the row.